# how to capture avfoundation in landscape mode instead of portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, avfoundation

need help here, been fixing for hours but to no avail.

i will like to capture a image and show a preview of it, in the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, it show in landscape mode. However when i grab the image it was shown as portrait mode.

i'm not sure why, i hope someone could help me :)

thanks for reading.

when live view
[image]

when captured and shown in uiimageview
[image]

```
- (void)addStillImageOutput
{
    [self setStillImageOutput:[[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init]];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil];
    [[self stillImageOutput] setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [[self captureSession] addOutput:[self stillImageOutput]];
}

   - (void)captureStillImage
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }

        if([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported]) 
        {
            UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

             if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
                 //NSLog(@"2222UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");

            [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
             }
             if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) 
             {//NSLog(@"222UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");

            [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
             }

        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection

                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);

            if (exifAttachments) {
               ////NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
               }
            else
            {
                         //NSLog(@"no attachments");

            }

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        //NSData *jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
        //UIImage *jpgImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:jpgImageData];
        [self setStillImage:image];
        self.imageExifDict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)exifAttachments;
                ////NSLog(@"NSdictionary from CFDict %@",self.imageExifDict);
//
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];

            }];
}
```

i pass the image from NSData to UIImage

```
self.capturedImage.image = [[self captureManager] stillImage];
```

Comment: Can you post some code please how you `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, it show in landscape mode`. I have the same issue.

Comment: @user2545330 edited my post. i hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i did with this C function:

```
UIImage *scaleAndRotateImage(UIImage *image)
{
int kMaxResolution = 2048; // Or whatever

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;

    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
}
```

This:

```
int kMaxResolution = 2048; // Or whatever
```

*because i used in new Ipad with that resolution*

More Info : http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/

Answer (score 1):

You missed one thing..
set the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer orientation according to the app orientation.

Eg:

For ios 6 and above use

previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation=AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;

for ios 5

previewLayer.orientation=AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;